# Getting Previous Date Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the before six months date using javascript.

I am using the following method.

```
var curr = date.getTime(); // i will get current date in milli seconds
var prev_six_months_date = curr - (6* 30 * 24 * 60* 60*1000);
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(prev_six_months_date);
```

Is this the right way or any better way to get the last six months date.

If this get fixed I want to apply this logic to get previous dates like last 2  months and last 10 years etc.

If any body give the solution in jquery also very helpful to me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you tagged it jQuery, you can replace `date.getTime()` with `$.now()`.

Comment: It has been a long time since this question, but still :
`var d = new Date();`
`d.setMonth(d.getMonth()-6)`

Similarly, you can use `setYears()` and `setDate()`

Answer (score 6):

**Add more functionality to the Date**

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function (n) {
    var time = this.getTime();
    var changedDate = new Date(time + (n * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    this.setTime(changedDate.getTime());
    return this;
};
```

**Usage**

```
var date = new Date();
/* get month back */
date.addDays(-30);

/* get half a year back */
date.addDays(-30 * 6);
```

No need for extra libraries, if this is only thing you need regarding dates. You can also create more functions to the Date's prototype according to your needs.

Comment: Great way to increase functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would look into [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/). It's well tested and has a very fluent interface for manipulating dates and times in JavaScript.

An example of using date.js:

```
(6).months().ago()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var curr = new Date();
var prev_six_months_date = new Date(curr);
var prev_two_months_date = new Date(curr);
var prev_ten_years_date = new Date(curr);
prev_six_months_date.setMonth(curr.getMonth() - 6);
prev_two_months_date.setMonth(curr.getMonth() - 2);
prev_ten_years_date.setFullYear(curr.getFullYear() - 10);
console.log(prev_six_months_date.toString());
console.log(prev_two_months_date.toString());
console.log(prev_ten_years_date.toString());
console.log(curr.toString());
```